# How to implement Python Set in C

Tags: python, c, stack, flood-fill

I have a question about how to implement a Python style 'Set' in C. I'm writing a flood fill algorithm, and it must use a stack-like list to keep track of which pixels are waiting to be coloured. I want the function to return the order in which the pixels are coloured (I'm using the algorithm to trace round lines from a starting point, and I don't want it to miss pixels as it goes along which must be hoovered up at the end - this behaviour happens with either a conventional stack or a recursive fill function).

By chance (prototyping code) I discovered that using a Python 'Set' as a stack gives the correct style of fill that I'm looking for. The two characteristics of this set that seem to be responsible for this are:

- FIFO behaviour
- When a pixel is added that is already in the set the set does not change (this doesn't actually seem to be a requirement but is a nice to have - I guess it depends on whether the increase in number of calls outweighs the overhead of searching the set for duplicates)

I can add pixels as linear indices so I can keep the queue integer based if that helps. Any ideas that don't involve a lot of looping?

Comment: Python sets are not FIFO.

Comment: A python set is similar to a mathematical set. Any element can only occur once in the set. [Wikipedia on sets as an abstract data type] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type))

Comment: @UpSampler-- this is not quite right. `{1, 2, 2, 3}` is a mathematical set, and it is [equivalent to the set `{1, 2, 3}`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Describing_sets).

Comment: Good point! @user2357112 I've just discovered this with some integer tests. However, it seems they behave as FIFO if you add tuples of pixels coordinates to them which is why my python code was working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want is a "unique queue" - perhaps you could reword the title of your question better to reflect this.

You can implement a unique queue by combining a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), which has set-like behaviour with O(1) performance, and a [doubly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list), which can be used like a queue.

```
typedef struct {
    hashtable *set;
    linkedlist *queue;
} unique;
```

When adding to the queue, you first check that the item isn't in the hash table already, and only if it isn't there do you add it to the hash table and the linked list. You can return `NULL` on successful addition, or the existing item if it's there already so the caller knows what happened:

```
void *unique_add(unique *uniq, void *data)
{
    void *existing = hashtable_find(uniq->set, data);
    if (!existing) {
        hashtable_add(uniq->set, data);
        linkedlist_add_tail(uniq->queue, data);
    }
    return existing;
}
```

When removing from the queue, you remove the item both from the linked list and from the hash table as follows:

```
void *unique_remove(unique *uniq)
{
    void *data = linkedlist_remove_head(uniq->queue);
    if (data) {
        hashtable_remove(uniq->set, data);
    }
    return data;
}
```

I have written a [hash table in C](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/hash-table.html) and a [linked list in C](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/linked-list-in-c.html), so you're welcome to use those for inspiration.

You could go further than this and make a data structure that is a hybrid of a hash table and linked list queue by using linked list nodes that have 4 pointers as follows:

```
struct unique_node {
    struct unique_node *next_in_queue;
    struct unique_node *next_in_bucket;
    struct unique_node *previous_in_queue;
    struct unique_node *previous_in_bucket;
};
typedef struct unique_node unique_node;
```

You would then implement the hash table buckets as linked lists using the `next_in_bucket` and `previous_in_bucket` pointers, while at the same time connecting the nodes in queue order using the `next_in_queue` and `previous_in_queue` pointers.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if you need to implement one by yourself, or if you could simply use a library like [Collections-C](https://github.com/srdja/Collections-C) which implements some basic data structures, including a queue(FIFO).

If you need to implement it by yourself, I will give you a short example code...

Comment: This seems like a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @DavidBowling the last line is intended as a placeholder if it is not enough to answer by giving a library

Comment: But as it is, it is _not_ an answer. It is just a link.

Comment: Thanks, I discovered queues (self taught programmer here... lot to learn!) while Googleing for the 'opposite of a stack'.

Comment: @Peter Greaves your welcome and good luck ;)